# id plus/minus in URL php?

Tags: php

I am working on PHPmySQL, i am currently displaying a specific record from database taking its ID in URL and showing the details on another page with the help of this id.

now i want to add a button named, NEXT RECORD, by clicking which id in URL increases by 1, page reloads and  shows the next record.
how do i do this, i am unable to find BUTTON in PHP.

what i am trying is,
to get the id:

```
    $id1=$_GET['id'];
```

to increase the id by one

```
    $new=$id1+1;
```

Comment: button needs to be created with `html`

Comment: What ???? What do you mean by `button in php` ? Are you sure you know the basics of html and php ?

Comment: Right, i have to make button in HTML, bu how do i then call its ONCLICK function to make changes in PHP script? thats what i was asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thankyou so much guys, i have gotn the answer,

```
 $id1=$_GET['id']; //takes ID from URL
 $new=$id1+1; //increments the ID by 1
 echo '<button type="button" onclick="window.location=\'pdetail.php?id='.$new.'\'">Next Record</button>'; //gives the new ID in URL of same page
```

thanks for ur time.
code is still in its initial stages, as it has no clue what happens when the records END.

Comment: Instead of writing your answer may I suggest that you would click the green tick beside the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Use HTML to make the button:

```
<?php
echo '<button type="button" onclick="window.location=\'record.php?id='.$_GET['id'] + 1.'\'">Next Record</button>';
?>
```

Comment: what i did was almost the same, bu its says that unexpected TSTRING?

        echo "<button type="button"   onclick="'pdetail.php?id='.$_GET['id'] + 1.">Next Record</button>";

Comment: Try: echo '<button type="button" onclick="pdetail.php?id='.$_GET['id'] + 1.'">Next Record</button>';

Comment: i am getting the ID in URL but its not increasing by one.

Comment: Include the window location on the onclick: echo '<button type="button" onclick="window.location=\'pdetail.php?id='.$_GET['id'] + 1.'\'">Next Record</button>';

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

**PHP**

```
$new_id = $_GET['id'] + 1; // Get the next id

// Function that gets the name of the current page
function curPageName() {
   return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1);
}

$new_url = curPageName() . '?id=' . $new_id;
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="?php echo $new_url; ?>">
<button name="NEXTRECORD" type="submit">Next record</button>
</form>
```

You can of course delete the function curPageName() if you want to write the page to which the button leads manually, but it will be much easier using this code if you have this code on several pages.

Comment: Yes, ur right, i want to plus one in id which is present in URL, then that id will display next record from database on the same page.

Comment: what is $v supposed to do? and shouldnt we concatenate $new_id with curPageName()?

Comment: ur technically right, bu as i am using SQL QUERY to show the results, this code generates conflicts with my query. Thankyou anyways